# A PHP Error was encountered Filename: core/Loader.php

Tags: php, loader

When I open my admin console my page gives me this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Only variable references should be returned by reference
Filename: core/Loader.php
Line Number: 178
```

I have found out the code and I have it this way:

```
 * @param   string  class being checked for
 * @return  mixed   class object name on the CI SuperObject or FALSE
 */
public function &is_loaded($class = '')
{
    if (isset($this->_ci_classes[$class]))
    {
        return $this->_ci_classes[$class];
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

I do not know what I have wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method return `boolean` CONST. But "Only variable references should be returned by reference". So your method `&is_loaded` must return variable reference.
You can remove `&` before method name. And I think your method should return `boolean` always because name `is_load` mean boolean return?

Comment: Yes of course... the problem is &.
I have removed and it works. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` sign before your function name sets the function to return a reference rather than a value. When you return `FALSE` you return a literal value, which is what causes the notice. As objects are always passed by reference, you can probably do without the `&` sign.